# why this asynchronous code won't break while loop?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

I use tornado asynchronous http client, but it doesn't work.

```
from tornado.concurrent import Future
import time
def async_fetch_future(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    my_future = Future()
    fetch_future = http_client.fetch(url)
    fetch_future.add_done_callback(
        lambda f: my_future.set_result(f.result()))
    return my_future

future = async_fetch_future(url)
while not future.done():
    print '.....'
print future.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must run the event loop to allow asynchronous things to happen. You can replace this while loop with `print IOLoop.current.run_sync(async_fetch_future(url)` (but also note that manually handling `Future` objects like this is generally unnecessary; `async_fetch_future` can return the `Future` from `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` directly, and if it needs to do something else it would be more idiomatic to decorate `async_fetch_future` with `@tornado.gen.coroutine` and use `yield`.

If you want to do something other than just print dots in the while loop, you should probably use a coroutine that periodically does `yield tornado.gen.moment`:

```py
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    future = async_fetch_future(url)
    while not future.done():
        print('...')
        yield gen.moment
    print(yield future)
IOLoop.current.run_sync(main)
```